# Wicket: Label with default text if model empty + CompoundPropertyModel

Tags: label, wicket, default-value

I have:

```
public FooPage( ... ) {
   this.setDefaultModel( new CompoundPropertyModel(new GenericIdLDM( Foo.class, 1)) );
   add(new Label("title"));
```

I'd like to have $subj.
I've found this solution from 2007 (point below) : http://www.mail-archive.com/wicket-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg29603.html
However, it wouldn't work for CPM as it needs the constructor with model.

How could I make it work with CPM?

```
public class DefaultTextModel extends AbstractReadOnlyModel<String> {

private final IModel<String> delegate;
private final String def;

public DefaultTextModel(String def, IModel delegate) {
    this.def = def;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

public String getObject() {
    String s = delegate.getObject();
    return (Strings.isEmpty(s)) ? def : s;
}

public void detach() {
    delegate.detach();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a custom `Converter` for your label. I think the better reflects your intentions as well. See for example https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/using-custom-converters.html#Usingcustomconverters-InWicket1.4

Other option could be JavaScript, check if the span is empty and then provide the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I can override Label#initModel():

```
protected IModel<?> initModel() {
    return new DefaultTextModel(defaultModel, super.initModel());
}
```

A simpler solution is to override Label#onComponentTagBody() and just apply the default text there.

(Sven Meier replied on the mailing list)